# python sysv-ipc create/attach/delete a shared memory

Tags: sysv-ipc

I need to start a process create shared memory, and then start other processes to read it. is there an example ?

run:
SharedMemory(9001,mode=666,size=9999,flags=IPC_CREX)

got:
sysv_ipc.PermissionsError: No permission to attach

run again:
got:
sysv_ipc.ExistentialError: Shared memory with the key 9501 already exists

Answer (score 0):

Your `mode` parameter should pass `0o666` in a octal form not in a decimal form.